# When using a gaussian link in GLM, what are the assumptions?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, least-squares, independence, assumptions, iid

In R, when I am fitting a model `glm(y~x, family = gaussian(link="log"))`, do I assume that $Y \stackrel{iid}\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ or do I assume that $Y \stackrel{indep}\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

I guess the point where I am confused is that I recall that in OLS regression, the Y is iid but in GLM Y is only independent. Now that I am using a link function that isn't the identity link, I am unsure which of the two assumptions is true.

Would this change for `glm(y~x, family = gaussian(link="identity"))`? If so, how?

Comment: We often assume normal errors in OLS, not a normal distribution of the response variable.

Comment: It is maximum likelihood under assumption of normal errors. If the error are not normal the estimator is still consistent (it is the same as in linear regression where there is no assumption of normal errors). There is an assumption of homoscedasticity for the reported standard errors (as there standardly is in linear regression as performed for example by the lm() command in R). Using car-package and command hccm() you can get heteroscedasticity robust errors. Y|X=x is normally distributed $\mathcal N(\beta_0 + \beta_1x,\sigma^2)$ if $\mathbb E[y\lvert x] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminology is confused, you say *gaussian link in GLM*, but *gaussian* is the *family*, not the link function. In your case the link function is logarithmic. In your notation, you also left out the predictors $x$.

So, with log link function and a linear predictor $\beta^T x$, the assumption is that $Y | X=x$ is distributed (independently) $\mathcal{N}(e^{\beta^T x}, \sigma^2)$ , while with *identity link function* it is distributed $\mathcal{N}({\beta^T x}, \sigma^2)$.